# Proper way to access an association of a newly inserted object in with MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis 3.4.6.

Let's say I have a POJO with an association, i.e.

#### Person

- PersonID
- CompanyID
- PersonName
- Company (Association to `Company` class)

#### Company

- CompanyID
- CompanyName

And, let's say I already have a DB full of `Company` records, but I'd like to add a new `Person` to `Company` with an ID of 1 and then subsequently retrieve my association.

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setPersonName("Ryan");
p.setCompanyID(1);

personMapper.insert(p);

Company c = p.getCompany() // I'd like to retrieve the association here
```

I know that I can just re-query my person and the association will be loaded, but is that the standard / acceptable way to accomplish such things?

I.e.

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setPersonName("Ryan");
p.setCompanyID(1);

personMapper.insert(p);

// In the below code, the "PersonID" **did** refresh from the DB after insert 
// so I have access to it, but my associations do not initialize after insert, 
/// so I have to re-query the DB to get a new Person object with my Company association
p = personMappper.get(p.getPersonID()); 

Company c = p.getCompany() // This will return as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you'd probably want to drop the `Person#companyID` field and just use `Person#company` to manage this.  When you're adding a new person, you need to know which company they are being a part of?

```java
Person p = new Person();
p.setPersonName("ryan");
p.setCompany(companyMapper.get(1));

personMapper.insert(p);
```

Now you have your `Person` with a full `Company`.  You'll need to make the second query regardless (so to answer your question yes, that is correct you would need a second query) but this way you can perform validations on the Company (ie. never assigning a companyId that doesn't exist).